# How to make an HTTP POST request in Gmail Contextual Gadget?

Tags: asp.net, http-post, gmail-contextual-gadgets

I’m developing a Gmail Contextual Gadget and now I’m faced with a Post Http communication problem. I don’t have any problem with get request, here’s is my get request code:

var mydata = { id: 10, name: 'sample1'};

```
var params = {};
var url = "https://myserver/handler/sample.ashx" + "?" + gadgets.io.encodeValues(mydata);
params[gadgets.io.RequestParameters.CONTENT_TYPE] = gadgets.io.ContentType.JSON;
params[gadgets.io.RequestParameters.AUTHORIZATION]=gadgets.io.AuthorizationType.SIGNED;
params[gadgets.io.RequestParameters.METHOD] = gadgets.io.MethodType.GET;

gadgets.io.makerequest(url,callback,params);
```

But when I need to make post request, I have a problem to getting mydata in server side. I checked all variable in request.Params, request.QueryString, request.Form. There is nothing!

```
var mydata = { id: 10, name: 'sample1'};

var params = {};
var url = "https://myserver/handler/sample.ashx";
params[gadgets.io.RequestParameters.CONTENT_TYPE] = gadgets.io.ContentType.JSON;
params[gadgets.io.RequestParameters.AUTHORIZATION]=gadgets.io.AuthorizationType.SIGNED;
params[gadgets.io.RequestParameters.METHOD] = gadgets.io.MethodType.POST;
params[gadgets.io.RequestParameters.POST_DATA] = mydata;


gadgets.io.makerequest(url,callback,params);
```

What is my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use gadgets.io.encodeValues to set POST_DATA

```
params[gadgets.io.RequestParameters.POST_DATA] = gadgets.io.encodeValues(postdata);
```

Or to isolate your data use this pattern:

```
 params[gadgets.io.RequestParameters.POST_DATA] = gadgets.io.encodeValues({
            Gadget_Post_DATA: gadgets.json.stringify(mydata)
        });;
```